# How to store List<String > in SQLite flutter?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, flutter-dependencies

In model  want to know have list  I want to know how to insert the data and retrieve the data.

Comment: In SQL databases, a "list of something" normally goes into it's own table. How does your database look so far?

Comment: I highly recommend the drift package for working with SQLite: https://drift.simonbinder.eu/

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
List<String> someListOfString = ["str1", "str2"];
const composeStr = someListOfString.join("&"); // I suggest you use separator which is not used in string
// Now you can save this string to SQLite
```

While retrieving:

```
List<String> originalList = composeStr.split("&");
```

Comment: That is simple. And horrible. It will work for a tutorial and then fail miserably in production.